# How to make my wordpress news site sync with my own personal server for my app

Tags: android, ios, sql-server, wordpress

I own a news site and wanted to make an app for it without having to write two different posts on both platforms, i wanted to be able to write  on wordpress and having send it to a server then i will be able to retrieve it and update my app, could someone please help?

Comment: Er, what? Why? What app is that? What does it do? Surely you can just get the news from the wordpress RSS feed?

Comment: Why `android` tag?

Comment: You have to write API services for Wordpress posts, then you can call those services in your Android App